# Intuitive meaning behind support, confidence, lift and conviction

Tags: data-mining, intuition, association-measure, association-rules

I'm learning about [association rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning#Useful_Concepts) and came across the common interestingness measures support, confidence, lift and conviction.

I'm interested in the intuition behind your decision-making process while dealing with those measures. What I'm looking for is practical advice which I can apply during my data analysis projects.

For example, the [second answer](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-good-threshold-in-association-rule-mining-for-support-and-confidence-in-order-to-have-reliable-rules) from Gericke Potgieter gives a good rule of thumb (high lift, low conviction) for determining the reliability of a discovered rule.

Some intuition which I commonly use:

```
higher support     --> rule applies to more records
higher confidence  --> chance that the rule is true for some record is higher
higher lift        --> chance that the rule is just a coincidence is lower
higher conviction  --> ?
```

What is your opinion about my intuition?

What are some of the heuristics/rules of thumb you use for making decisions regarding the above-mentioned measures?

Comment: Hi @anna, did you find the answer you are looking for?

Comment: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.150.6616&rep=rep1&type=pdf 

I hope this paper helps

Comment: This paper called **Selecting the right objective measure for association analysis** https://www.cse.msu.edu/~ptan/papers/IS.pdf can help you, because he explains when you may use a measure like `confidence` or `lift. He also explains some intuition behind the measures with nice examples, and also the formulas and the properties.